# Run query across all databases in a server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql server with many databases and most of them have identical structure, however there are a few that are not the same.

I want to search for a specific value of an attribute in one of the tables and modify that value to something else. I know how to do this per database but I've never ran a query across all DBs in a server.

Essentially what's the easiest way to do this without having to go and run a set of commands one by one in each database? so in summary. :

Edit: What I need help with specifically is the commands to iterate the commands for every database, and a check statement to only run whatever commands I need only if "tableA" exists while querying a DB.

```
for every database in server
assert 'tableA' exists
  if exists
    value 'johnny' in column 'fname' of 'tableA'
         replace 'johnny' with 'sara'
    else
        do nothing
```

Comment: Is this mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: @Sean Lange I am not sure, however I am accessing the databases through phpmyadmin of a WHM installation, so I guess it would be through mysql?

Comment: yes, that would be mysql

Comment: OK, is this possible to do through mysql?

Comment: construct a loop (such as an array of database names with a `foreach`) and iterate through it, each loop being a different database

Comment: Heidsql, a mysql client, has such functionality,although you`ll have to update the fields manually,it will only find them for you.

Comment: @Martin you are correct, this seems the only way I have found to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some long searching for an answer I see that there is no easy way of doing it. As user Martin mentioned on a comment the only way possible through MySQL is to run an external script to automate the tasks.

Essentially my approach was to create a php script using an array that has the login information for each database(i.e. db name, user, pw) and then stepping through that array and executing the sql commands with a loop for each db.